# SWIFT Apple Mach-O Linker Error "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFExectur"

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode6-beta6

Trying to use Parse with X-code and objective C.  4 different errors pop up.  Suggestions?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFExecutor", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
    l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_BFExecutor_$_Background in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTask", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in Parse(PSObject.o)
    objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFile.o)
    objc-class-ref in Parse(PFNetworkCommandRunner.o)
    objc-class-ref in Parse(PFQuery.o)
    objc-class-ref in Parse(PFRetryingCommandRunner.o)
    objc-class-ref in Parse(PFTaskQueue.o)
    objc-class-ref in Parse(PFUser.o)
    ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTaskCompletionSource", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
    objc-class-ref in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
    objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFile.o)
    objc-class-ref in Parse(PFNetworkCommandRunner.o)
    objc-class-ref in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Add Bolts.framework in to project...

Comment: perhaps the Bolts framework fat binary doesn't include x86_64 (64 bit) executables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the Bolts.framework as well.  That's why you are getting those errors! :-)

Comment: @JoshuaArcher The Bolts framework comes in the same package as the Parse SDK.  Just look in the download folder and you'll find it.